# How to Change Hue and Saturation of a MovieClip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics

I have myself a movieclip that has multiple images in, I want to be able to use AS3
to change the Hue and Saturation so the client can choose a colour and it will change the colour of the movieclip to their settings.

I have tried this

```
var my_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
my_color.color = 0x550000;
tempPlayer.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
```

But the movieclip just becomes completely red, I just want to be able to add a touch of colour, and then make the colour stand out a bit using AS3. Basically something like this
[image]
but from grey to one colour

Canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saturation it gets a little more complicated than the traditional `ColorTransform`. Often, you will need to use [`ColorMatrixFilter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html).

This feature is quite complicated, but [this blog post](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/28/understanding-as3-colormatrixfilter-class/) describes the process quite well and gives you code for a couple common effects.

That said, you *can* add just a little color to an object with `ColorTransform` by using the `*Offset` and `*Multiplier` properties like [`greenOffset`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#greenOffset) and [`redMultiplier`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#redMultiplier). This lets you offset the red, green or blue values a little to give different effects.